# Why did Kylo Ren admit to being a monster?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *Star Wars: The Last Jedi* there is one scene between Rey & Kylo Ren when they are force-linked, where Rey calls Ren a "murderous snake" and a "monster".

Although Kylo begins to point out what he perceives as Rey's ignorance of past events, he does not deny what she stated and replies, *"I am a monster."*

Now perhaps this was just a disarming tactic, *but are there any other reasons with some sufficiant evidence to prove what Kylo Ren's motivations were here in not fighting Rey on her characterization of him?*

Answer (score 5):

> are there any other reasons with some sufficiant evidence to prove what Kylo Ren's motivations were here in not fighting Rey on her characterization of him?

Very simply put, **because he didn't want to fight with Rey**. He was reaching out for contact, not for a "yes it is"/"no it isn't" argument.

I read Kylo's statement as an acknowledgement of perspective, i.e. "Yes, I know *you see me as* a monster". He's not agreeing with Rey objectively, he's just acknowledging her point of view.
Whether that is done genuinely or simply to disarm her is left up to interpretation of the viewer.

Keep in mind that Kylo and in the past Anakin have been well aware of the impact of what they are doing, they simply think their actions are a *necessary evil*.

Comment: His decision to go to the dark side was not without conflict and regrets. And, certainly, killing his own father wasn't done because he's a complete sociopath without feelings.  He could very well *actually* agree and feel that he is something of a monster.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I honestly can see either characterization, even though I do suspect that there could be an interesting philosophy behind Ren's motivations and/or that he's been listening falsely to the wrong person the whole time mistaking them for someone else (ie: mistaking Anakin for Palpatine), but I am looking for answers or hint of answers in things like the novelization or interviews from Eps/Writers/Cast about this particular scene, but perhaps it will rely on information in TROS.

Comment: @DarthLocke - My claim here was that it was probably a complicated, murky mix of things, and I thought the answer was somewhat black and white.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: I don't quite see how the answer is black and white. It specifically nuances both Kylo's opinion on himself and on how other perceive him.

Comment: @Flater - I don't see anything in there that indicates that there might be some remorse or conflict - you state, "quite simply" that it's to avoid fighting Rey, and that someone else might view their actions as evil, or that, while unpleasant, they are necessary.  None of that indicates any feelings of actual conflict, just others not having the capacity to understand.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet If it were black and white, Kylo wouldn't have anything to do with Rey as she is predominantly aligned against him. My point was more that Kylo doesn't see himself as the monster that Rey does (i.e. pure evil) and that he merely verbally agrees but not really in meaning. I think the last paragraph of the answer captures the "remorse or conflict" well enough in calling their actions (from their POV) a necessary evil. It entails admitting it's evil, but (allegedly, according to them) the right response in the given context.